# Toggle the visibility of an element when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to perform an exercise where I toggle the visibility of an element by accessing its ID. I can get it to disappear when I click it. However, I don't understand what is wrong with my code so that it doesn't reappear when clicked.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  if (button.style.display === "none") {
    button.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1Text">Hello world</p>
<button id="button">Buttonni</button>
```

Comment: A button that has style `display: none` can't be clicked, or receive any other events. It is not visible and no user interaction is possible, until some code runs for some reason that makes it visible again. And the button click hander is not going to run.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the button disappear once it is clicked. Is that what you mean to make disappear?

Or are you trying to make the following paragraph disappear upon button click?

```html
<p id="p1Text">Hello world</p>
```

If that is what you want to make disappear, you have to change the `getElementById` to the correct ID.

Currently, you are doing:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
```

which is getting the ID of the button, instead, get the element of the paragraph

```js
let button = document.getElementById("p1Text");
```

That should fix it

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to use element.classList.toggle to achieve this senario.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

```js
const hello = document.querySelector('.hello');

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  hello.classList.toggle('hidden');
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1Text" class="hello">Hello world</p>
<button id="button">Buttonni</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem if by 'disappear' you meant the paragraph to disappear, but not the button, as referred to in your code above.

Please check the code below. I hope it helps you.

```js
    const paragraph = document.getElementById("p1Text");
    const button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.addEventListener("click",() => {
      if(paragraph.style.display === "none" || paragraph.style.display ==="") {
        paragraph.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        paragraph.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
```